# add css @media from Google Chrome Styles tab

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, media-queries

There is no problem to add pure css

```
.myclass1{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

via Google Chrome Styles tab (F12 -> Styles tab -> click on + sign to add styles).

However, I'm having difficuitlies to add a media query

```
@media (min-width: 800px){
    .myclass1{
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Just added: I would like to add similar css to what is on the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going into styles try the main html in the left panel, right click the head tab and click on edit as HTML then just add your code.

Comment: Do you mean to use style="" in the html code? That would be fine, but could you please tell me how to specify media query in a style attribute? Thank you.

Comment: no edit the head tag as html and add use <style>code here</style>